# How to add a menu tab to a node to link to an information page to be used by author?

Tags: 7, theming, routes

I just need some direction from module developers. I would like every node to have an 'information page' that the author can easily view. When they are logged in and viewing the node, I'd like it to appear as a link right along side that node menu bar (where it says "Edit, Revisions, Devel" etc.), called menu tabs.

I'm not very familiar with custom modules, but I'm simply looking for the basic framework, or an example module, that will add that menu link, and also allow me the place to begin adding my code.

I'm basically trying to display Google Analytics data for each node.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Examples for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module, particularly the menu_example sub-module. You are looking to create a MENU_LOCAL_TASK-type menu. This should get you started.